# Image overlapping on small screen

Tags: css, overlapping

Apologies if this has already been answered, I couldn't find the right information

Hi All

I'm struggling to find what I believe is a simple solution to this problem.

www.keepdry.co.uk

In a small screen (mobile handset etc) the images overlap and the logo disappears behind the goal posts. In a large screen they sit far enough apart to be separate.

I'm sure the answer is simple, but what do I need to do to allow the images to shrink dependant on screen size/resolution but have a minimum width for the whole image so as not to distort too far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//HU" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">;
<html>
<head>
  <title> keepDRY.co.uk </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="players"></div>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="fence"></div>
  <div id="carabiner"></div>
  <div id="pouch"></div>
  <div id="comingsoon"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should start by not using absolute positioning for all elements.

Comment: please post the code....

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//HU"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head> 
 <title> keepDRY.co.uk </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">  
 <link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

</head> 

<body>
<div id="players">
</div>
<div id="logo">
</div>

<div id="fence">
</div>

<div id="carabiner">
</div>

<div id="pouch">
</div>

<div id="comingsoon">
</div>

</body>

</html>

Comment: Wow... That's not what we meant. Please put the code into the question.

Comment: Not sure how to paste all the CSS code but the link to it is here: http://www.keepdry.co.uk/css/main.css

Comment: Ha! Can you guess I'm new to this? Wasn't sure what information was needed and didn't want to overload the question

Comment: Hey if I were you I would learn how to position elements right. http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ and here is another. http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is responsive images.

Here is [an article](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/) about different options.

The simplest way:

```
img {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```